# Hibernate @Filter does not work in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I'm using JPA with Hibernate as a JPA provider. I cannot figure out how to configure my entities to apply a hibernate filter to a One-to-Many association.

I have a `Master` with a collection of `Details`. Here are my entity definitions:

```
@Entity
public class Master extends Base {
    private List<Detail> details;

    @OneToMany
    @OrderColumn
    @JoinTable(name = "master_details")
    @Filter(name = "notDeleted")
//    @Where(clause = "deleted = 'false'")
    public List<Detail> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(List<Detail> details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
}

@Entity
@FilterDef(name = "notDeleted", defaultCondition = "deleted = false")
public class Detail extends Base {
    private Boolean deleted = false;

    public Boolean getDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(Boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }
}
```

The `Base` is nothing special but a simple `MappedSuperClass`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Base {
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

When loading a `Master` by `entityManager.find(Master.class, mid)`, the filter should prvent all `Details` from loading but I checked the sql queries generated by hibernate (by `show_sql=true`) and no where clause is added when loading details of the master !!! A sample query generated by hibernate is:

```
select
    details0_.Master_id as Master1_6_1_,
    details0_.details_id as details2_1_,
    details0_.details_ORDER as details3_1_,
    detail1_.id as id7_0_,
    detail1_.deleted as deleted7_0_,
from
    master_details details0_ 
inner join
    Detail detail1_ 
        on details0_.details_id=detail1_.id 
where
    details0_.Master_id=?
```

After some search there was some hints that "loading by id will not use filters, use queries" so I tried the following but no gain :(

```
entityManager.createQuery("from Master where id=" + mid).getSingleResult();
```

But just if the `@Where` above getDetails is uncommented (instead of `@Filter`), its clause is added to the query generated by hibernate (but I cannot use `@Where`)

Comment: I have the same problem and I can confirm the _loading by id will not use filters, use queries_. If you had more info on why it is so, it would be great. Also by _loading by id_ we mean `session.get(Entity.class, id)`, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Hibernate `@Filter` needs to be manually activated via `enableFilter` method:

```
session.enableFilter("myFilter").setParameter("myFilterParam", "some-value");
```

However, filters are useful when you need to parameterize the filtering condition. And, you don't seem to need a dynamic filtering clause.

For this reason, you could use the Hibernate `@Where` filter, like this:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Where(clause="deleted=false")        
public List<Detail> getDetails() {
    return details;
}
```

This way, you should get the list of non-deleted `Detail` entities.

Comment: '1<>0' is just used to show a trivial condition. You'are right, bad idea :)

Comment: "For this reason, you could use Hibernate @Where" - Depends on whether he needs to activate/deactivate on convinience